# Как задать позиционирование внутреннему div, чтобы он занимал всю ширину экрана

Tags: html, css

```css
 .one{
        position: relative;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }   
    .two{
        position: absolute;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        top: 35px;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `.one` убрать `position`. В `.two` добавить `left:0`

```css
 .one {  
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   width: 600px;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }
 
 .two {
   position: absolute;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: #ccc;
   top: 35px;
   width: 100%;
   left:0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вытащите второй div из первого, и добавьте в стили второго дива `width: 100vw;` и `left: 0;`

```css
    .one{
        position: relative;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }   
    .two{
        position: absolute;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        top: 35px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
    }
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```